# Language not updating to Hebrew android

Tags: android, xml, locale, android-preferences

I have application which has English as primary and hebrew as other language. The problem I am facing is language not showing or updating.

I have added two qualifiers "he" and "iw" but nothing is working. Unable to find the problem. But when I am switching Language from device setting its working fine.

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
}
```

Here is my SettingActivity.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    ViewGroup toolbar, toolbarBack;
    BoldCustomTextView toolbarTitle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbarBack = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_back);
        toolbarTitle = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
        toolbarTitle.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_settings));
        toolbarBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);

            ListPreference languagePreferences = findPreference("language");

            languagePreferences.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(getContext(), newValue.toString());
                    return true;

                }
            });
        }


    }


}
```

Here is my Application class

```
public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication {



    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"));
        MultiDex.install(AppController.this);
    }
}
```

Here is my Root Preferences

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/setting_behaviour">

        <ListPreference
            app:entries="@array/language_entries"
            app:entryValues="@array/language_values"
            app:key="language"
            app:title="@string/change_language_settings"
            app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is my arrays

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="language_entries">
        <item>English</item>
        <item>Hebrew</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="language_values">
        <item>en</item>
        <item>iw</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

After Setting the New Locale, start the app again

```
fun triggerRebirth(context: Context?) {
    val packageManager = context?.packageManager
    val intent = packageManager?.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.packageName)
    val componentName = intent?.component
    val mainIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName)
    context?.startActivity(mainIntent)
    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
}
```